# Autofac - Resolving IEnumerable Generic Interface at runtime

Tags: c#, autofac

I found out how to resolve at runtime a generic interface using the below code. How would I resolve ALL instances of `IGenericInterface<>` to get back collection at runtime. I know in autofac we are supposed to use `IEnumerable<T>` but I don't know how to represent that in the below example:

```
 var typeInRuntime = typeof (SubClass1);
 var instance1 = container.Resolve(typeof(IGenericInterface<>)
                          .MakeGenericType(typeInRuntime));
```

This does not work obviously

```
 var typeInRuntime = typeof (SubClass1);
 var collection = container
                .Resolve(IEnumerable<typeof(IGenericInterface<>)
                .MakeGenericType(typeInRuntime)>);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to build the generic `IEnumerable` type in two steps. The following code works on my machine ;)

```
var t1 = typeof (IGenericInterface<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(SubClass1));
var t2 = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(t1);
var collection = c.Resolve(t2);

Assert.That(collection, Is.InstanceOf<IEnumerable<IGenericInterface<SubClass1>>>());
```

Comment: What if I don't know what SubClass1 will be at the time? As in, I want to resolve all the types which implement that interface.  I essentially need to lookup what SubClass1, SubClass2, SubClass3 are.